# Failed to find the required terraform minimum version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using tfenv to switch terraform versions.Lately I'm getting this error and i'm not sure how to solve this.

Can someone pls let me know what is happening here, why its not able to detect min-required version?

Error:

```
tfenv install min-required && tfenv use min-required && terraform init -backend=false ./stage; terraform validate -var="api_key=xxxx" ./stage
Error: Could not determine required_version based on your terraform sources.
Make sure at least one of your *tf files includes a required version section like
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.0.0"
}

see https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html for details
tfenv-min-required failed
grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced
No versions matching 'min-required' found in remote
```

Makefile:

```
DUTY_VAR=-var=api_key=xxxx test:    tfenv install min-required && tfenv use min-required && terraform init -backend=false ./stage; terraform validate ${DUTY_VAR} ./stage
```

Terraform folder/file structure:

```
|-terraform (directory)
|-modules ( directory)
|   - main.tf
|   - variables.tf
|   - versions.tf
| 
|-stage(root-module)(directory)
|   - backend.tf
|   - main.tf
|   - .terraform-version
|   - providers.tf
```

version.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.11.13"
}
```

backend.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.11.13"

  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "nonprod"
    key            = "tfstate/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::zzzzzzz:role/yyy"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `tfenv` to know exactly what's up here but this error seems to be a bug or misbehavior of one of [`tfenv min-required`'s `grep` calls](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/blob/c0e74190b5a3560fb90276cdc8ab49d0f3abf7b3/libexec/tfenv-min-required#L77). I think you might have encountered [`tfenv` issue #246](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/issues/246).

Comment: ya, but this is happening only when modules and root-modules are defined in same repository, and strangely its not detecting the required_version. Is there something wrong on how the versions are defined?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts in this answer as explained below,

#### Part 1

As specified in the error, please try to specify the terraform version in `required_version` setting as below,

```
required_version = ">= 0.11.13"
```

Please note the `>=`

#### Part 2

As per the Terraform documentation, modules should constrain only their minimum allowed versions of Terraform and providers, such as `>= 0.12.0`

Please refer the [Terraform Version Constraint Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/version-constraints.html#terraform-core-and-provider-versions)

So instead of Terraform version `0.11.13`, try with version `0.12.0`